# spinner item in android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Hi i have to develop one spinner example in android.here i have to used below code:

```
public class InsertionExample extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/update?wsdl";

private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
Button btninsert;
String selectedItem;
private int i;
static final String KEY_NAME = "orderid";
static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_status);
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);
    String[] DayOfWeek = {status, "Q", "P", "F", "I", "C"};
    for(i=1;i<DayOfWeek.length();i++){
        if(DayOfWeek.get(i).equals(status)) {
            DayOfWeek.remove(DayOfWeek.get(i));
        }
    }

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_insert1);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent in = getIntent();
             String orderid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
             String status = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);
             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
             PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
             unameProp.setName("Status");//Define the variable name in the web service method
             unameProp.setValue(selectedItem);//Define value for fname variable
             unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable

             request.addProperty(unameProp);
             PropertyInfo idProp =new PropertyInfo();
             idProp.setName("Orderid");//Define the variable name in the web service method
             idProp.setValue(orderid);//Define value for fname variable
             idProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
             request.addProperty(idProp);

             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             try{
                 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                 SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                 TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                 result.setText(response.toString());
             }
             catch(Exception e){

             }
         }
    });


    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           R.layout.row, R.id.country, DayOfWeek);
     //set the view for the Drop down list

     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}


public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) { 
         selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

This is my for loop:

```
  for(i=1;i<DayOfWeek.length();i++){
        if(DayOfWeek.get(i).equals(status)) {
            DayOfWeek.remove(DayOfWeek.get(i));
        }
  }
```

Here i got below error on for loop:
**Cannot invoke length() on the array type**
**Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type 
 String[]**

How can i remove this above error.please help me.
 String[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DayOfWeek.length // no function!
```

and

```
DayOfWeek[i] // operator []
```

and read these documents:
[Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

and by the way: You can't remove items from an Array in Java. As @Gabriel said, maybe an ArrayList is better suited for your needs here.

Comment: ok fine thanks for gave this good suggestion.here i have one doubt.if i have to run the app means first the previous activity status is displayed.here my previous activity is C means C,Q,P,F,I,C displayed on spinner box.stillnow ok.But i wish to display the first item is previous activity status.here my previous activity is C means wish to display on spinner box is C,Q,P,F,I,C.here my previous activity is P means wish to display on spinner box is P,Q,F,I,C.how can i do???here what condition i have to put here

Comment: that's a completely different question and not trivial. Start a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

String[] DayOfWeek is a table. If you want to get it's lenght just use DayOfWeek.lenght . Without (). And you don't get item on position i by DayOfWeek.get(i) but DayOfWeek[i]. It's Java. Not C#.

Answer (score 1):

It's `DayOfWeek.length`, not `DayOfWeek.length()`. It's a (final) variable of the array, not a method call.

In your case, an `ArrayList<String>` will serve you better, seeing you want to remove from the array (which you can't).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an element from an array.
You better use an arraylist which has an option to alter your data in the arraylist.